# Adding workflow to custom content types

Tags: 7, nodes, workflows

I am trying to assign a workflow to my custom content type, but i can't find the option to get this working. Is it a bug or maybe just not part of the [workflow module](https://drupal.org/project/workflow)?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably suggest to use [Workbench Moderation](https://drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) instead of using the Workflow module. I don't know your exact use case, but I've had a lot of luck with the Workbench suite.

Comment: I would like to use workflow, 'cause there is also a module called og workflow, which is the final purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The workflow module comes with two other modules **workflow node** and **workflow field**.

> **Workflow Node** *Adds a Workflow to nodes. (Use only if you come from a version below 7.x-2.x. If not, use 'Workfow Field' instead).*
>
> **Workflow Field** Defines a Workflow field, widget and formatter. (Do not enable Workflow Field and Workflow Node together.)

If you're using workflow 7.x-2.0, you should enable **workflow field** module and create a new field (say "State") in the content type and select field as **workflow** with a widget of your choice (defaults to workflow). When you visit after creating content, you can use the field to change the state (workflow state).

You'll get handy options in the field settings like 'allow scheduling', 'adding comment to transition' etc.